# Анонимность в сети

Tags: vpn, proxy

Сейчас легко можно идентифицировать пользователя помимо ip. Например по подписи браузера (там собирается вся инфа о системе+заголовки http+куки+локальные хранилища). Вот пример сайта, который вычисляет уникальность по такой схеме http://panopticlick.eff.org/

Вопрос такой: чем пользоваться и что лучше использовать, чтобы нельзя было вычислить по такой схеме?

P.S. Ведь даже если постоянно чистить куки, локальные хранилища этого мало, да и javascript не отключишь (ведь многие сайты его используют в своей работе). Нужно же помнить что у flash тоже есть свое локальное хранилище и т.д.

И еще вопрос: Если я переустановлю OS, то можно ли будет по подписи браузера идентифицировать данный ПК?

Comment: И да, никакой подписи браузера нет.

Comment: под подписью подразумевается совокупность информации о системе+заголовки+прочая фигня, с помощью которой можно идентифицировать ПК

Comment: Есть только заголовки, "прочей фигни" нет. По http заголовкам ПК не идентифицируют, хотя бы по тому, что кроме USER-AGENT ничего интересного там нет. А user-agent это версия браузера, и на 99% такой же версией пользуется ваш сосед.

Comment: вы не учитываете какую информацию можно собрать с помощью javascript, java.

Comment: Мухахах, какую ? Версию моего кота?

Comment: Конечно сложно сходу понять что можно собрать серьездного для идентификации джаваскриптом, но ведь этот сайт собирает http://panopticlick.eff.org  А вообще боятся наверное стоит больше того, что могут уникальный айдишник куда нить запихнуть (помимо cookie и локального хранилища браузера много вариантов есть).

Comment: Да ничего он там не собирает, поймите же наконец, то что он показывает находится в заголовках http, и нет никаких уникальных айдишников. Разберитесь с этим и вам сразу станет спокойнее.

Comment: @pyatak, а как же evercookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да хоть для домохозяйки

[tor](https://www.torproject.org/) + [окно в режиме инкогнито](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=ru)

Comment: Как вы считаете есть ли смысл к тору подключаться по прокси?

Comment: Да и правильно ли я понял, что тор - это что-то на подобии защишенной цепочки прокси?

Comment: Вы вторым комментарием ответили на первый. Да это отчасти цепочка прокси, а к прокси через прокси уж масло масленое, но технически никто не мешает.

Comment: ничего подобного, сеть тор атакуется 24 на 7 и часть узлов в ней зловредные, так что  добавление в цепочку внешнего прокси на входе и на выходе  может существенно усилить секьюрность,

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, начнём с установки сети **Tor**, **I2P** и **FreeNet**. Нужна связка **Tor** + **I2P**, тор будет выступать корнем(Подробней о том какие страны не рекомендуется выбирать любых сетей [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365831/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#answer-1365839)), а поверх тора будет сеть I2P, далее советуется к установке **DNS Crypt** и **DNS over HTTPS**, для того чтобы предотвратить утечки **WebRTC**, **Time Zone**, **SSL**, **Canvas**, **WebGL**, **Font** и т.п. рекомендуется к установке **Tor** браузер или **LibreWolf/Waterfox** с соответствующей конфигурацией. Для поиска рекомендуется мета-поисковой движок **SearXNG**(Подробней о серверах SearX [тут](https://searx.space)). В основном это то что хватит для повседневного анонимного использования интернета, но по-хорошему стоит ещё докупить blockchain(домашний) и поменять **BIOS** на **LibreBoot**(или типа того), а для деления файлами используйте OnionShare т.к. qbTorrent и подобные ему клиенты для передачи файлов используют ваш настоящий IP адрес, а **OnionShare** использует сеть тор для передачи файлов, в целом для краткого экскурса этого вполне достаточно.

О том как не стоит защищать свою анонимность:

1. Голый Tor - во-первых голый тор легко идентифицируется и по нему можно выяснить отправителя запроса, во вторых это в принципе не безопасная сеть в голом виде.
2. Режим Инкогнито - современные Fingerprint системы могут легко определить является ли пользователь в режиме инкогнито или нет, и соответственно могут узнать как оптимизировать слежку за пользователем.
3. Бесплатные и коммерческие VPN - во-первых они все собирают и продают логи, во вторых они спокойно выдадут все ваши запросы и IP адрес по первому же запросу "плохих" людей.
4. Использовать проприетарные операционные системы(по типу MacOS и Windows).
5. Использование проприетарных браузеров(и другого софта) и расширений в них.
6. Использование проприетарных веб-сервисов.