# В чем заключается анонимность?

Tags: безопасность

Думаю многие представляют на базовом уровне как устроен тор. Везде написано что тор обеспечивает анонимность и приватность, по поводу приватности никаких вопросов нет, но что насчет анонимности?

Представим что мы зашли на какой-то сайт через тор в n часов n минут, сайту высвечивается ip выходного узла, а не наш, но ведь выходной узел это такой же участник мировой сети, а значит он выходит в мировую сеть через провайдера, а он ведет логи... Соответственно мы(например власти какой-то страны) можем посмотреть эти логи и соотнести время захода на сайт и ip которые обратились к выходному узлу в n часов n минут(грубо говоря), таким образом мы можем найти промежуточный узел, по такому же принципу можно пройтись по всей цепочке и найти наш реальный ip.

Как по мне, это просто немного усложнит поиск нашего реального ip. Единственное что я могу предположить, так это то, что мы сливаемся с остальными участниками сети, но как-то не вселяет мне все это доверия, ведь если мы не обычный пользователь, а например нежелательный политический оппонент, и нас ищет не вася пупкин, а государство, то не вижу проблем найти реальный ip, даже у нас куча связок впн с прокси и всего остального.

С другой стороны, многих киберпреступников либо не могут найти, либо находят через большой промежуток времени.

Вопрос, что я не понял? За счет чего обеспечивается анонимность?

Comment: Как минимум, запросить логи у провайдеров всех нужных стран будет весьма проблематично

Comment: Я хочу похвалить автора вопроса- "за проницательность". по моему, в области информационной безопасности надо начинать с того, что ничего не следует принимать на веру :-). Да, мне тоже всегда казалось, что атака на тор путём наблюдения за ЗАГОЛОВКАМИ всех пакетов на всех нодах - возможна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что все узлы находятся по всему миру и политические соперники не будут выдавать логи своей страны сопернику и из-за этого логи собрать спец. службам одной страны будет невозможно, но если к примеру брать страны подписавшие соглашение 14-ти глаз то тогда страны участвующие в договоре могут передавать данные разведки между друг другом, таким же образом правительство США обходит закон о невозможности слежки за пользователем своей страны.

Страны участвующие в соглашении 14 глаз:
США, Англия, Канада, Австралия, Новая Зеландия, Дания, Нидерланды, Франция, Норвегия,
Германия, Бельгия, Испания, Швеция, Италия.

Ссылки:

- [Закон о запрете слежки](https://agenda-u.org/news/ssha-perestanet-sledit-za-svoimi-grazhdanami)
- [Контракт 14 Глаз](https://wikiless.org/wiki/UKUSA_Agreement#9_Eyes,_14_Eyes,_and_other_%22third_parties%22)

Answer (score 2):

Вы все верно понимаете. Однако, на целевой узел вы попадете, пройдя множество таких узлов в сети ТОР (а они находятся по всему миру), и пройти этот путь, ой как сложно до источника запроса.
Это большой геммор - отследить источник, но, конечно, можно. И, кстати, трафик там не шифруется.